# Firebase leaderboard prevent cheat

Tags: javascript, firebase

I need to implement a leaderboard/score system into a multiplayer game based on firebase ( javascript ) for a client.

Now my question is there's a way to prevent cheating for a leaderboard?

The problem is if i let the player/client to write their own score at the end of a game the client can always rewrite the score.

If its possible i wouldn't like to obfuscate my code.

Comment: This is covered in depth in the security section - you can add a simple parameter that requires that no data exists before you can write it.  In this way, data can't be rewritten.  You could add further parameters as you see fit.  That being said, this could have been found with a basic google, or any time on firebase website.